# Intel Galileo - Building Linux Image on OSX not working

Tags: macos, yocto, intel-galileo

I'm following [this](http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/building-image-for-intel-galileo-on-osx.html?_escaped_fragment_#!) and [this](http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergey-s-blog/intelgalileo-buildinglinuximage) links to build a Yocto customized image to galileo board on OSX 10.7 machine.

The Yocto version used is 1.0.1;

When i run `bitbake image-custom` in `meta-clanton_v1.0.1` dir console start like build, but returns the following:

```
$ ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1 > bitbake image
The BBPATH variable is not set
DEBUG: Removed the following variables from the environment: TEX_PATH, rvm_version, rvm_path, ...
DEBUG: UI 'knotty' does not require extra cache!
DEBUG: Found bblayers.conf (~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1/conf/bblayers.conf)
DEBUG: LOAD ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1/conf/bblayers.conf
$ ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1 >
```

but stop there. if i do in build folder:

```
$ ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1/yocto_build > bitbake image
ERROR: Unable to parse ./poky/meta/conf/layer.conf: file ./poky/meta/conf/layer.conf not found in ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1/yocto_build
$ ~/meta-clanton_v1.0.1/yocto_build >
```

I'm doing something wrong?
I changed files according instructions provided in links.

Where can i set BBPATH?

Thanks for any possible help

this is my full oe-buildend-internal: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wiTAAduK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error, the one about `BBPATH` not being set, that is what you'll get when you try a build outside the `build-dir`. Thus, you should go into your `build-dir`, like you do in your second attempt.

Regarding the issue in the 2nd attempt, how does your `conf/bblayers.conf` look like? Without having seen that file, it looks like you have a direct reference to `./poky/meta`...

Of course, in the end it might also be related to OSX, I've run OE and `bitbake` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks anders; sorry for long time in response. I do not have anymore MacOSX. Now that i'm under linux, i will try build on it.